# Allowed memory size exceeding 256mb on simple mysql select query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

EDIT: For anyone finding this at a later date CI will use alot of memory in these sorts of circumstances since it will create an object for every row (using result_array() doesn't seem much better), so the best bet is just to use PHP's built in mysql functions. If you're using MYSQLI you can access the connection link like so:

```
$this->db->conn_id
```

I'm trying to run a script through the command line (testing for what will be a cronjob), what the script does is irrelevant since it is failing at the first select and doesn't get any further.

I am using Codeigniter 2.0.3.

My table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `graphic_files` (
  `graphic_file_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `graphic_file_style_id` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `graphic_file_fm_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `graphic_file_config_line` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `graphic_file_config_line_hash` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `graphic_file_location` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `graphic_file_pack_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `graphic_file_enabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `graphic_file_alternative` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `graphic_file_version` decimal(4,2) NOT NULL,
  `graphic_file_time_added` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `graphic_file_time_modified` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `graphic_file_size` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`graphic_file_id`),
  KEY `graphic_file_style_id` (`graphic_file_style_id`),
  KEY `graphic_file_fm_id` (`graphic_file_fm_id`),
  KEY `graphic_file_config_line_hash` (`graphic_file_config_line_hash`),
  KEY `graphic_file_pack_id` (`graphic_file_pack_id`),
  KEY `graphic_file_enabled` (`graphic_file_enabled`),
  KEY `graphic_file_version` (`graphic_file_version`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=240752 ;
```

There are 240,000 rows.

I am trying to select around 120,000 of them with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM graphic_files WHERE graphic_file_enabled = 0 AND graphic_file_style_id = 5
```

But I get an allowed memory size error like so:

> Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 92
>   bytes) in
>   xxx/codeigniter_2.0.3/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_result.php on
>   line 167

I realise the simple answer is that i'm out of memory, but this seems ridiculous for simply doing a select query, especially with a high allowed memory size of 256mb.

Can anybody suggest a reason for this? Could it be to do with codeigniter and the way it builds the results object?

Comment: Why don't use `LIMIT`? Do you really need all 120,000 records in one query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With big data u need to use `mysql resource` instead of CI functions

```
$result = $this->db->query($sql);
$resource = $result->result_id;
while($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($resource)) {
    // do the magic
}
```

Comment: Mysql can handle big queries using its own memory engine, PHP don't. I assumed you are using `->get_where()` or similiar method, so CI is going to load all data to array.

Answer (score 9):

Ok, assuming that we're dealing with the bare minimum (just using declared sizes here), each row of data is 624 bytes.  That's a bit of an understatement because many of those variable width fields take additional space to note how large they actually are.  Given that all of them are going to be converted to an internal PHP style, we can probably tack on a bit more there (results returned as an array, possibly a hash depending on settings).  But in actuality we're probably going to be dealing with a total of almost 2kb per record after it's all said and done.

Also, we're dealing with 120,000 of them.  120000 * 2048 = 245760000 bytes = 234.4 MB of data.
PHP has it's overhead, and so does codeigniter.  Together, that's more than enough to push you over the memory limit.

If you want a better estimate of how much memory is being used, go ahead and crank up the memory usage limit, then after you do your select query, check [memory_get_usage()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php).

What you can do to cut down on memory usage is either thin down the number of rows being selected by adding additional where clauses, select only the necessary columns instead of all of them, or use a LIMIT statement.  If you go the LIMIT route, you can process all the records and all the columns, but in chunks.  Each select statement could return a limited number of rows, say 100, but you could make each subsequent call resume where the other left off.  That way you'll never have more than 100 rows of data in memory at a given time.

Comment: Good math, I hadn't investigated it to that level of detail. Limiting could be a solution, i'll attempt to adjust my code and see how it holds up

Comment: +1 for suggesting limit. Also think about what happens when you have more data added. You might come up with a workaround (e.g. increasing the memory limit), but once you get to a certain size of data, this will no longer work.

Comment: I've done some more testing and gotten it working through a mix of the two answers. I'm very thankful for your detailed answer and although it was good and you had a number of upvotes I noticed a massive difference in using PHP's built in SQL functions instead of CI's and further investigation showed that a large part of the problem was due to CI creating objects for every row which used alot of memory, so I feel obliged to accept the other answer for anyone that finds this at a later date. Very sorry if I could somehow give you SO points I would, thankyou very much for the answer.

Comment: For better memory usage, you should use `SplFixedArray` for fetching database records. Row count is known so it's perfect for storing the result in `SplFixedArray`. Alternatively, if you can, you could use `Judy` for storing db records. `SplFixedArray` is using about 40% less memory than native PHP ones. `Judy` uses even less. Your recordset could fit in the memory using one of the two mentioned.